# Git alias does not find the path I supplied

Tags: git

I'm trying set up a git alias because I type this command often:

```
git commit -m 'update' -- hdf5_classification/output
```

To make the alias I am doing:

```
git config alias.up '! git commit -m 'update' -- hdf5_classification/output'
```

but when I try to use the alias by typing `git up` I get the following error: `error: pathspec 'hdf5_classification/output' did not match any file(s) known to git.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your command works for me, if hdf5_classification is in the top-level directory of the repo.

From the git-config man page:

```
Note that shell commands will be executed from the
top-level directory of a repository, which may not necessarily be
the current directory.
```

I suspect the command you want is:

```
git config alias.up 'commit -m "update" -- hdf5_classification/output'
```

which runs git commit in in the current directory, because it is not a shell command (because it does not start with "!").

Side note: you are using single-quotes inside single-quotes in your command, which happens to work, but isn't doing what you think it's doing, I think :-)

Comment: Thanks! What is the difference between single-quotes and normal quotes with regard to this command? :)

Comment: The difference here between single quotes and double quotes is just that in your command you are trying to include one set of single quotes inside another, which doesn't work since the shell interprets the quote at the beginning of the word update as the END of the first quoted string, not the beginning a quotation inside the other one.

Comment: By using different types of quotes, I can have the double quotes inside the singles, without accidentally closing the singles.